# Is it possible to perform other operations in the codeblock of the sort method (arr.sort)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use the `arr.sort` method on an array to sort it in ascending order, and while sorting, `splice` duplicates+original with something like `newArr.splice(newArr.indexOf(a),2)` `when a==b`. Nothing was happening though. When I changed the `splice` to a basic `c+=1` operation, nothing happened either. Are you unable to do such operations within the `.sort` method? And why? I would have thought they'd be separate commands that run alongside the sort method (i.e. c increasing by 1 each time an arr.sort condition runs is separate from what arr.sort outputs).

```
//Sort array in ascending order: newArr.sort((a,b) =>a===b?0:b>a?-1 :1)
//trying to apply other operations within the codeblock via c

    var c = 0
    newArr.sort(function(a,b){      
    if(a===b){
      c+=1
      //c doesn't increase at all tho
      return 0
      } else if(b>a){
        return -1
        } else{
        return 1
        }
      })
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @richytong The original reason was to see if I could splice out duplicates as noted above; currently the reason is just learning what I can/can't do in javascript. Like with the c+=1 example above, could be useful to have a numbered value of how many times the condition runs.

Comment: How about `noDupes = new Set(arr)`? Better to explain what you're [trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in addition to your attempt, because it may not be a good way to do it. I strongly caution against incrementing counters to see how many times `.sort` called its callback comparator, which is an implementation detail that your code shouldn't worry about.

Comment: If you declare and initialize an "newArr" array before, it work...

Comment: `c` does in fact increment in your code so long as you have duplicate values in `newArr`.

Comment: Invent whatever you want but the answer will always be no, it is not possible to apply other operations in the code blocks of a sorting method. (As your title requires)

Comment: @MisterJojo "invent whatever you want"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to `uniq` and then `sort` your array. In general, `splice` is an expensive operation; I would find a way around it.

```js
const uniq = arr => Array.from(new Set(arr))

const sort = arr => arr.sort()

sort(uniq([5, 5, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5])) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

You don't want to mess with stuff out of scope, especially for something that you could express linearly. `sort` is something you probably don't have to optimize.